# Directory not found for option '-L/Users/..../TestFlightSDK1.1'

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I am trying to archive my Xcode project, but its giving some warning like this:

> Directory not found for option '-L/Users/..../TestFlightSDK1.1

It won't be there in that path, I removed that Folder from my project. I've tried all answers in Stackoverflow, but its not working.

- I cleaned my project
- I deleted all values in my `Target -> Build Settings -> Library Search Paths and Header SearchPaths`
- I looked onto my `project.pbxproj`

But I  didn't found any sign `TestFlightSDK1.1`

How can I solve that warning?

Comment: Delete the Derived folder in the Organizer.

Comment: i tried, but its also not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know how it solved yet. I removed some of my Third Party Libraries and again i added them. I did the same in `Link Binary With Libraries` in `Build Phases`, removed some of the `libraries` which is used by Third Party Libraries. It worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Happened to me after upgrading to Testflight SDK2.
In Build Settings, I looked into "Library Search Paths" and there was still a reference to the SDK1.
I did it for each Target (main and test), and build for main target and ran tests, and the error disappeared.

Comment: for me i had some search paths under Framework search paths that were old/non existent, so took them out and the warnings went away

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Dir from **Library Search Paths** from **Build Settings**

1. Set the Project
2. Click on Build Settings.
3. Search for Library Search Paths.
4. Remove Invalid dir path from list.
5. Clean Project.